# iPhone Populating Table With UITextFields

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin

Can tables be populated with type UITextField?  If so, how could this be done?

I have attempted a few different implementations, though each failed.  Please let me know if you've achieved something similar in the past and how you did so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog) it does wonders

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UITableViewCell

Register it in your tableViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[TableCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"tableCell"];
```

Make sure tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: looks something like this:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

In the custom cell's initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        UITextField *textField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 600, self.bounds.size.height)];
        [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [self addSubview:textField];
    }
    return self;
```

}

The textField size needs tweaking, as does the word-wrap and lots of other practical bits to get the input and output working but this gets the textField into the tableViewCell.

Hope that helps, 
Steve